# Selenium Automation java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have this code which gets me the link and name of each mega menu and dropdown I want to click all the mega menu and dropdown and then continue when I try the .click method it shows Stale Reference. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 public static void DropdownItemsDetails(List<WebElement> itemLists) {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemLists.size(); j++) {
                WebElement dropdownItem = itemLists.get(j);

                // Get the dropdown item text and link
                String dropdownItemText = dropdownItem.getText();
                String dropdownItemLink = dropdownItem.getAttribute("href");

                // Print the link and name
                System.out.println("Dropdown Item: " + dropdownItemText);
                System.out.println("Dropdown Item Link: " + dropdownItemLink);
            }
        }
public static void countAndRetrieveNavbarItems() {
            // xpath for mega menu.
            List<WebElement> megaMenuXpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'navbar')]//a[contains(@class, 'menu')]"));

            // hover object creation
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

            // total navbar items
            int megaMenuCount = megaMenuXpath.size();
            System.out.println("Total Mega Menu Items: " + megaMenuCount + "\n*************************");

            // Iterate through both navbar items and dropdown items
            for (int i = 0; i < megaMenuCount; i++) {
                System.out.println("==========================================================================================================");
                WebElement megaMenuItem = megaMenuXpath.get(i);
                // Perform hover action on the navbar item
                actions.moveToElement(megaMenuItem).perform();
                // Get the navbar item text and link
                String navbarItemText = megaMenuItem.getText();
                String navbarItemLink = megaMenuItem.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println("MegaMenu Name: " + navbarItemText +"\n==============");
                System.out.println("MegaMenu Link: " + navbarItemLink+"\n==============");

                // Check if the dropdown is present for the current navbar item
                try {
                    WebElement dropdownContent = megaMenuItem.findElement(By.xpath(".//following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'dropdown-content')]"));
                    if (dropdownContent != null) {
                        // Get all the dropdown items
                        List<WebElement> dropdownItems = dropdownContent.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                        System.out.println("Dropdown item count: "+dropdownItems.size()+ "\n*************************");
                        //get dropdown details
                        DropdownItemsDetails(dropdownItems);
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    // Dropdown not present, continue with the next navbar item
                    System.out.println("No dropdown for this menu: "+navbarItemText);
                    continue;
                }
                // if end validation
            } // for end navbar item
        }
```

I tried the megaMenuItem.click(); after System.out.println("MegaMenu Link: " + navbarItemLink+"\n=============="); this line it gave me this error:org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementReferenceException` indicates that the reference to an element is now stale i.e. the element no longer appears within the HTML DOM of the page.

`WebElement` is not an object itself, it is a link to an object.
Clicking on menu item you triggered one of events:

1. Dropdown menu is disappeared and not exist anymore (so object is not exist, but link to it still present as far as you got it before)
2. Click on dropdown triggered transition to another page.

In any case to continue operations with dropdown, you need to open it again and get array of it's elements.

Depends on you case it can be done triggering back via browser if transition on another page was performed and clicking on dropdown element or just clicking on it.

Comment: Can you show it to me via code. It would help me understand better. My requirement is to access each megamenu and its related dropdown link.

Comment: @SameerMohsin I need reproducible example from you to show you on real case.